Manga where the main character gets kicked out of party then hero disbands party once he finds out
I’m trying to find this one manga where the main character gets kicked out of the party, one of those stories, but later the hero finds out why he was kicked out and then he disbands the party since he was a friend of the main character. If I remember, the party itself was called Dawn.

do you remember what type of story it is? sucked into a game, VR game, isekai, ? also do you remember where you read it?

It was a video on youtube that I saw. It was just another one of those fantasy ones where the mc has a skill that's overlooked but his friend didn't know the lengths that the other party members did to get rid of him so he disbanded the group as a response.

Possibly Banished from the Hero's Party, I Decided to Live a Quiet Life in the Countryside

Red was once a member of the Hero's party, a powerful group destined
to save the world from the evil forces of Taraxon, the Raging Demon
Lord. That is, until one of his comrades kicked him out. Hoping to
live the easy life on the frontier, Red's new goal is to open an
apothecary. However, keeping the secret of his former life may not be
as simple as he thinks. Especially when the beautiful Rit, an
adventurer from his past, shows up and asks to move in with him!

So we have:

protagonist was kicked out from hero's party by a comrade (but not the hero)
when hero learns of it, she leaves the party to look for him
hero is protagonist's sister, not friend; but this is Japanese manga, so lines between older brother, friend, boyfriend get blurry...
I don't recall and couldn't find the name of the party

